# Reload all open tabs on localStorage item change javascript

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to reload the pages of a particular site on all the open tabs when the value in the local Storage changes. How can I achieve this?

Comment: If the localStorage element changes, you are probably the one who does it in your code right? Just refresh the page after you change it with `location.reload();`.

Comment: Best way to handle this is clear the local storage while Log out of old user(i.e. Before Log in of new user)

Comment: I want to reload all the open tabs.

Comment: No this is not a new sign in just a user switching accounts.

Comment: Then make a singleton service and inject it in a component that every tab has. In this singleton service create an rxJs Subject that you update, when you update the localStorage item.

Answer (score 3):

You can subscribe to [storage events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/storage_event) like this:

```
window.addEventListener('storage', function(e) {  
    // Some storage value changed. Reload tab!
});
```

As noted in the linked documentation:

> The storage event of the Window interface fires when a storage area (localStorage or sessionStorage) has been modified in the context of another document.

Do note this is limited to tabs which have access to the same local storage (limited by the domain of the website).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution to refresh all using the same Angular Application

**Step 1:** Make a list of all Opened Tabs With a unique ID.

```
const myTab = sessionStorage.tabID ? sessionStorage.tabID: Math.random();
let tabList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('tabList'));
if(!tabList) tabList = {};

tabList[myTab] = { refresh: false, updated_ts: new Date() };
localStorage.setItem('tabList', JSON.stringify(tabList));
```

**Step 2:** Monitor Activity in local storage. [This can be done in a number of ways]

```
setInterval(function(){ 
  let tabList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('tabList'));
  if(tabList && tabList[myTab] && tabList[myTab].refresh){
    delete tabList[myTab];
    localStorage.setItem('tabList', JSON.stringify(tabList));
    console.log("Do refesh");
    // location.reload();

  }
  else{
    console.log("Don't refesh");
  }
}, 3000);
```

**OR** (Subscribe to storage events)

```
window.addEventListener('storage', function(e) {  
    // Your logic
});
```

**Step 3:** Trigger Refresh

```
function triggerRefesh() {
  let tabList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('tabList'));
  if(tabList) for (const tabID in tabList) tabList[tabID].refesh = true;
  localStorage.setItem('tabList', JSON.stringify(tabList));
}
```

> **Note:** You should not reload an angular application, rather route to your authentication page or refresh your component