# How to Automatically Refresh the First Browser Tab Based on Changes Made in the Second Tab?

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm new to Angular. I'm facing big issue with existing Angular application. It has a dropdown with several countries such as Japan, USA, China and Australia. In this application when a user selects a country from the dropdown, data such as user details and country details, is loaded onto the webpage.

My concern is,

If a user opens another browser tab, and selects a different country from the dropdown, and loads the related data, again he returning to the first tab, and it won't display the data related to the newly selected country until the browser tab is refreshed.

I'm looking a solution to automatically refresh the firstly opened tab when the user **only** changes the country dropdown selection in the second tab. How can I do this using Angular?

Comment: The solution is a websocket.  However, your problem is the same problem all websites have, not just Angular, so not sure your fixation on fixing it.  Most users innately understand this is an issue and would likely not be trying to maintain two different browser tabs at once.  Look into websocket, otherwise, there is nothing else we can offer without any code to work from.

Comment: This is very interesting question. @PsiKai can't he do it using local storage? Something like this. 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56987578/reload-all-open-tabs-on-localstorage-item-change-javascript

Comment: Yep that could work as a stop-gap.  For same browser, but not cross browser or private/incognito window.  It's also only one state value, so not a huge deal.  I probably wouldn't ship that outside of a personal project, but definitely another option.